# Using Compass functions without using Compass to compile stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby, sass, gulp, compass

I am currently working on a project that uses Sass to compile my stylesheets. I have discovered that I would like to do some trigonometry in my CSS, however, and thus have turned to Compass for support.

In order to use the trig functions supported by Compass, must I use the framework to compile my stylesheets? (I.e. refactor my gulp workflow to use compass, instead of Sass, as my stylesheet manager?)

Given that Compass is built on top of Sass, do I understand correctly that there is no way for me to use compass' functionality (mixins, or trig functions, for example), while still using plain Sass plugins to manage my stylesheets (like gulp-ruby-sass)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm breaking your question up into two parts.

**Can I use Compass mixins without Compass?**

*Yes*. Compass mixins are just chunks of SASS that you can include in your project. For example, if you wanted to include the Compass border-radius mixins in your project, you could simply include the [border-radius partial from the Compass core](https://github.com/Compass/compass/blob/stable/core/stylesheets/compass/css3/_border-radius.scss) in your project. This will work without compiling through Compass.

**Can I use Compass trig functions without Compass?**

*No*. It looks like the trig functions rely on Ruby code in the Compass core. I'm not very familiar with Ruby, but I don't think there is a way to include that in your project without compiling through Compass.

Comment: Thanks Steve! That's what I had garnered from my own recent perusal, re: functions, at least. Thanks for the confirmation, and the details specific to mixins.